# Send HTTP POST through FileMaker Pro

Tags: http-post, filemaker

I'm trying to do a simple image POST to a php script through FileMaker Pro. I have the image in a container. Is there a way to post this to my URL so that I can use the normal PHP upload etc to take care of the processing? Any plugin etc that can help me do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I know of is to use a third party plug in like:
http://www.troi.com/software/urlplugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't just "get" the contents of the container you'll need to write the container to disk and then use a plugin like troi file to "read" in the image data. You may also want to use a plugin like troi text to encode the image before uploading (base64 is pretty common) and then decode it on the php side.

Comment: Actually, I just used the container as the parameter to base64 encode function and used that in post method. No need to write to disk. Anyway, my question was regarding the actual post, not the encoding but thanks for the answer anyway.